Whether the proposal "Simd-96", which was agreed in May 2024, has been updated on the mainnet or not?
In early May 2024, the community has been created a proposal called "Simd-0096', which was about cancelling the burn of priority fee in transaction. And this proposal has been agreed by the community voting. So I just wanna ask whether the proposal has been updated on the mainnet or not?
